# Remove space above sections

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

Redefining sections commands with titleclass{page} and titleclass{top} from titlesec results in unwanted white above the headings.

How can this white space removed properly (without eye-tweaking with negative spaces)?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum,parskip}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleclass{\section}{page}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleclass{\subsection}{top}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem Ipsum}

\subsection{Dolor sit amet}
\lipsum[1-3]


\section{Some Text}

\subsection{Some more Text}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why did you change the class of `\section`?

Comment: Because I want section titles on a dedicated page and subsection titles always on top. The titleclasses page and top were looking like the proper approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{showframe, lipsum, parskip}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{-4.5ex}{0pt}
\titleclass{\section}{page}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{-4.5ex}{0pt}
\titleclass{\subsection}{top}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem Ipsum}

\subsection{Dolor sit amet}
\lipsum[1-3]


\section{Some Text}

\subsection{Some more Text}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

*Edit*: This simpler code does not depend on the font size used fir section titles:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{showframe, lipsum, parskip}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\titleformat{\section}{\clearpage\Huge\bfseries\Huge}{\thesection}{1em}{}[\clearpage]

\titleformat{\subsection}{\clearpage\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem Ipsum}

\subsection{Dolor sit amet}
\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{Some more Text}
\lipsum[5-6]

\section{Some Text}

\subsection{Some more Text}
\lipsum[7-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like the desired output. Could you elaborate where the 4.5ex white space is coming from? Why is it not supressed with \titlespacing*{...}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm trying your solution with different font sizes now. Bigger sizes (e.g. \Huge) are giving that unwanted white space again. Therefore I'm looking for a general solution, that removes the  space without manually tweaking by eye for every font size.

Comment: @halifaxone: Please see my edit. I propose a new,  simpler code, without changing the class.

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem. However I'm still wondering about the white spaces when using \titleclass{...}{...}. Do you have any idea why they occur?

Comment: No precise idea. It must be hard-coded in `titlesec` to mimic the defaults of `\part` and `\chapter`. There's a similar problem with package `titling` (used  for cuustom `\maketitle`s), which provides the `\droptitle` length.